# MongoRepository prevent recursive dbref

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I've got a mongo collection that looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "brand1ID",
    "brand" : "brand1"
    "competitors" : [
        {
            "$ref" : "brands",
            "$id" : "brand2ID",
            "$db" : "my-db"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "brand2ID",
    "brand" : "brand2"
    "competitors" : [
        {
            "$ref" : "brands",
            "$id" : "brand1ID",
            "$db" : "my-db"
        }
    ]
}
```

and a Java class like so:

```
public class Brand {
    
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String brand;

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<Brand> competitors;
}
```

I figured that if I put `@DBRef(lazy = true)` on the competitors property in the Java class that it would not load the competitors in the child, but this doesn't seem to be the case. If I don't put it it just breaks with error as response, if I do put it it returns with about 150 iterations and then error about stack overflow. Is it anyhow possible to achieve this behavior? If not, what would be the alternative? I can't have them embedded since all entries would be brands of some sort and they would all have competitors that would be other brands. The desired result when looking up "brand1" would look something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "brand1ID",
    "brand" : "brand1"
    "competitors" : [
        {
            "_id" : "brand2ID",
            "brand" : "brand2"
            "competitors" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

This is probably more of an SQL job, but I'm stuck with Mongo. One idea would probably be to just save IDs to a list and then query for them separately, but I'm trying to do this in a single query.

Comment: Why you use `DBRef`? In [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/) says `...it makes sense to store related information in separate documents, typically in different collections or databases.` In your case, I think is redundant.

Comment: So basically using DBRefs is the same as if I were just storing the IDs in the document and then looking them up myself through another query in Java... That's a bit disappointing. Thanks.